# How to Configure a Boosted Tree Model

Tags: azure, machine-learning, decision-tree, azure-machine-learning-service

I wanna configure a boosted decision tree but don't know how to do it, i know the meaning of every parameter but not the best value i have to assign to it.

- Here is the parameters :

**Maximum number of leaves per tree** : i put ( 60,100,200,300 )

**Minimum number of samples per leaf node** : i put ( 10,30 )

**Learning rate** : i put (0,1)

**Number of trees constructed** : i put (2000,5000,6000)

**Random number seed** : i put (4)

The problem is how to know if you put the right values or if you did not overfit the model ?

Comment: Use cross validation.

Comment: the problem is not how to not overfit but to understand every single parameter and not put values randomly. that's my issue :(

Comment: Read the official documentation and you'll get an idea about the parameters and how to choose the best parameter values without overfitting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn906025.aspx

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne i did but its not mentioned how to really choose, its only an explanation of every parameter not how to use them. if you get my issue :(

Comment: Ok.. For that you should go though some documentations on how the algorithm is working and trial and error is also a good option to go with

Answer (score 0):

If you are using more than one value of a parameter (**for example you put Maximum number of leaves per tree as 60, 100, 200, 300**) on a specific algorithm (**not just Boosted Decision Tree algorithm but all algorithms in Azure Machine Learning**), you have to consider using [**Tune Model Hyperparameters**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905810.aspx) module.

This module reiterates the Machine Learning experiment for you. It will give you the tuned parameters, and then display its corresponding metrics/results.

Just **replace your Train Model module with Tune Model Hyperparameters module**.

[image]

The "tuned" parameters look like this (I specified 5 runs/iterations on the Tune Model Hyperparameters module)

[image]

In the example screenshot above, if you focus on getting the highest accuracy / coefficient of determination of your sample regression model, you can use the parameters displayed on the fourth row.

Hope you can replicate this on your end. :)